# AWS EventBridge - Use output of first target as input to the next

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-event-bridge

A rule in AWS EventBridge allows us to provide upto 5 targets. For each of these targets, we have some options to choose the input - based on the event that matched the rule. Is there a way to pass the output of the first target (lambda function) as the input to the next (another lambda function).

I know we can do this by triggering an SNS at the end of the first lambda function. But, I am looking for a way to do this within the EventBridge.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to do this would be to have Eventbridge hand over the event to a Step Functions state machine and have 5 steps in that state machine.

Step functions allow you to consume output from first step in the second step and so on.

More on Step Functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/how-step-functions-works.html).

More on Lambda with Step Functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @paritosh answer that Step-functions makes more sense for a workflow but if you need something more light-weight (and don't want to learn one more thing); you can use set Eventbridge as the lambda destination. Lambda should then send the event back to Eventbridge via a PutEvents api call https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

If you want to change the input before triggering the lambda, you can use InputTransformer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/transform-input.html